# What is the significance of Lord Hanuman on flags?

Tags: hanuman, symbolism

It is often seen that triangular saffron flags have the silhouette of *Lord Hanuman* on them, what is the significance of this? What does this represent, or what is the myth(story) behind this?
**Edit**: If according to the answer by *Suresh Ramaswamy* it is due to the story of Arjuna and Lord Hanuman then which source/scripture describes this story?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per Mahabharata, once Arjuna was on the seashore.  He saw a small monkey jumping up and down.  The monkey claimed to be the strongest on earth.  Laughing Arjuna built a bridge of arrows, but hardly had the monkey set foot on it, it broke,  A number of times Arjuna made stronger and stronger bridges, but each time the monkey jumped on it and broke it.  At last with all his knowledge and skill Arjuna constructed an almost indestructible bridge, but this too the monkey destroyed.  Arjuna decided to end his life, when a small boy (Sree Krishna in disguise) appeared and asked Arjuna to try once more for the last time. At the same time he revealed himself to the monkey (who was none other than Hanuman) as Sree Rama. The monkey told Arjuna, that the loser would serve the winner at all times.  Arjuna agreed. This time the bridge was unbreakable.  Hanuman revealed himself to Arjuna and as promised agreed to serve Arjuna.  Arjuna bowed before Hanuman and requested him to be part of his standard and Hanuman rose up and settled on Arjuna's standard which was saffron in colour.

Hence the saffron flags depicting the silhouette of Lord Hanuman on them is a reproduction of Arjuna's standard - his flag.

Comment: please add necessary references to the story.

Comment: According to Mahabharata, it is Bhima who asks his brother Hanuman to mount the flag of Arjuna. This story of Hanuman, Arjuna and Krishna doesn't appear in Vyasa Bharatam.

Answer (score 2):

Emblem of Hanuman is the sign of victory. The following quote comes from [*Bhagavad-gītā* (verse 1.24)](https://vedabase.io/en/library/bg/1/20/).

> *atha vyavasthitān dṛṣṭvā*
>   *dhārtarāṣṭrān kapi-dhvajaḥ*
>   *pravṛtte śastra-sampāte*
>   *dhanur udyamya pāṇḍavaḥ*
>   *hṛṣīkeśaṁ tadā vākyam*
>   *idam āha mahī-pate*
>
> **Translation**
>
> **At that time Arjuna, the son of Pāṇḍu, seated in the chariot bearing the flag marked with Hanumān, took up his bow and prepared to shoot
>   his arrows. O King, after looking at the sons of Dhṛtarāṣṭra drawn in
>   military array, Arjuna then spoke to Lord Kṛṣṇa these words.**
>
> **Purport**
>
> The battle was just about to begin. It is understood from the above
>   statement that the sons of Dhṛtarāṣṭra were more or less disheartened
>   by the unexpected arrangement of military force by the Pāṇḍavas, who
>   were guided by the direct instructions of Lord Kṛṣṇa on the
>   battlefield. The emblem of Hanumān on the flag of Arjuna is another
>   sign of victory because Hanumān cooperated with Lord Rāma in the
>   battle between Rāma and Rāvaṇa, and Lord Rāma emerged victorious. Now
>   both Rāma and Hanumān were present on the chariot of Arjuna to help
>   him. Lord Kṛṣṇa is Rāma Himself, and wherever Lord Rāma is, His
>   eternal servitor Hanumān and His eternal consort Sītā, the goddess of
>   fortune, are present. Therefore, Arjuna had no cause to fear any
>   enemies whatsoever. And above all, the Lord of the senses, Lord Kṛṣṇa,
>   was personally present to give him direction. Thus, all good counsel
>   was available to Arjuna in the matter of executing the battle. In such
>   auspicious conditions, arranged by the Lord for His eternal devotee,
>   lay the signs of assured victory.

Comment: I think "kapi-dhvajaḥ" just means ape-bannered, not Hanuman-bannered.